# Push changes from fork as multiple pull requests

Tags: git, github, pull-request

We have forked a Github project and are making changes to it. For each task I create a separate branch which I later merge onto the `master` in fork.

So right now I have a `master` on work which is like 20 commits ahead of the `master` in the original repo.

The rule in this project is to `create pull request for each task`.

Although, I know how to do it in `git`, I am not sure about the process.

What I am not sure is how I can create pull request for Task 1 which is in the 2nd commit, then for Task 2 which is in the 5th commit, etc. ???

Did I make a mistake and I can now create pull request only for multiple fixes at the same time?

Should I have done like this:

- fix a task
- merge with master on the fork
- create pull request from fork master to original master ?

EDIT

@OliverCharlesworth What you suggested is the way I worked in the past, but it brought many issues. Since I first fix a few tasks, then create PR for each, it created many conflicts with the master (in vain). So each time I created PR, I got a message that it cannot automatically merge but I have to solve conflicts first. Then for 90% of PRs, I had to deal with merge and lost a few hours only on merging.

This is the reason I thought I am doing it wrong.

So when I switched to a rule "fix 1 task then merge to for master", I avoided all these silly conflicts and saved ours on merging.

Since you say that "make PR from the branch" is the right way to go, how to avoid silly conflicts and not lose a few hours on silly merging process?

NOTE: when I say "silly", it means that all conflicts resolve back to the same pieces of code having to be fixed. something that will never happen when I follow the new rule.  Silly means "lose hours on merging without good reason".

Comment: If you push changes to your master branch (which is a fork), the pull request you made on the upstream repo will update and show all commits that are in your master branch. AFAIK there's no way to avoid this, unless you create one extra branch per task and commit to that, and make a PR for all of them.

Comment: The solution is not to merge to master on your fork.  Create a PR from the branch back to the original repo.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Please check EDIT. It was too long for a comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just push your branches-per-task to your forked repository and then open pull requests for those branches. You can create pull requests for any branch `X` to any branch `Y`, you don't have to create a pull request from `master` to `master`.

Comment: Please see my EDIT. I did this in the past and ended up each time spending a few hours on silly merging.

Comment: The PR from task-branch **is** the way to go. You will have the same merge conflicts that you have if you merge your branch to `master` and open a pull request from there. Before pushing your branch and opening the PR you should fetch from upstream and rebase your feature branch on top of `upstream/master`, then the PR will have no conflicts.

Comment: The most time-consuming thing was that I had to handle the same conflicts with the master when I merged PR. It was very frustrating to lose 2h merging the same and same things each time.

Comment: also can you edit your answer and explain more about "...Before pushing your branch and opening the PR you should fetch from upstream and rebase your feature branch on top of upstream/master, then the PR will have no conflicts". I pushed from the upstream only to sync fork master with remote master after merging PRs.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean with "merging" the same things over and over again. Maybe you should have a look at `git rerere`?

Comment: The situation is like this. I want to PR merge fork repo onto original master. It says I cannot as I have to resolve conflicts. So I have to return to fork, resolve conflicts in it, then merge to "fork master", then push changes to "original repo". This does not look right IMHO. Because the flow is like this: (FORK)create a branch, pull into it and resolve conflicts, merge to master, push to upstream, push to fork master.

Comment: What don't you like with that? At least if I got you right. You create a branch in your fork, you work in your branch, you update your branch by rebasing against upstream/master to be mergable without conflicts with the latest changes done on upstream/master (of course you can rebase your fork master against the upstream/master and rebase your branch against your fork master too, just one command more) then you push your branch to your fork, make a pull request to upstream and if it got merged you can update your fork master from upstream/master.

Comment: Yes that's the flow. Seems too much steps IMHO. However, I am glad that it's the proper way.